# C#: how to use object in

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, class

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and developing in c#.

When I create new controls (boxes, check-boxes,etc) within the GUI (drag and drop) the objects are created in the class called `Main`. I need these objects out of that class, so I have declared public static objects in order to use them in other classes.

The problem is that when I modify something in the GUI, Visual Studio generates new code erasing my changes in the `initialize components` section.

How can I get passed this?

Comment: Objects declared as public static are almost never a good idea. Show us the code of what you want to achieve...

Comment: @TomasPastircak, *almost never a good idea*, why?

Comment: It sounds like you're modifying designer files directly, which you aren't supposed to do. Why do you think these classes need to be static (they don't).

Comment: If you need checkboxes in another class, you can make new ones.  It doesn't cost you a penny.  There is no sane reason to have to share visual objects between classes.  You are probably making the mistake of using your visual components as either 1) Storage for important state information, 2) Containers of business logic, or even worse - both.  Don't do this!  There are countless powerful tools available in C# for interfacing objects, message passing, events, delegates... learn how to use them.

Comment: Only the Form's class should actually have to touch UI objects. Your other classes should do non-UI work and then call the methods of the Form class to update the visuals. Using static members like that makes it really easy to shoot yourself in the foot when you want to expand later. It also breaks encapsulation and makes it harder to read and debug.

Comment: That said, if you [edit] you question to better describe your situation - to show what information you are trying to share and why, then you might get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

The class that you are modifiying is a partial class of the actual forms class (called a designer file).

There is actually a comment at the top of the designer file saying that you should not modify it!

```
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
```

The form that the controls are used on should be the only place they are directly referenced (so the designer file). When you move something around the form (such as putting a text box at the bottom that was at the top); visual studio updates the designer file with the new position information.

If you are trying to create shared controls so you do not have to keep defining them perhaps you should look at creating user controls which can have their own code behind. Take a look at the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx) for information.